# array_key_exists contains string

Tags: php, arrays, array-key-exists

I am using array_key_exists on an associative array to detect if a key exists like this...

```
if (array_key_exists('Packaged price (£3.00)', $item))
{
echo 'The Key Exists';
}
```

This works fine, but I want to modify it so that it checks if the key has packaged in the name.  So instead of checking just for 'Packaged price (£3.00)' it would also work for the following...

```
Packaged cost (£3.00)
Packaged price (£17.00)
Packaged Item
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop through all the keys and check if any key contains the term `Packaged`

```
foreach($items as $key=>$value)
{
      if(stristr($key,'Packaged')!==FALSE)
         echo "Matching key is: $key";
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/8TCvii9l)**

Answer (score 1):

array_key_exists will not work in that case it will perform exact match, for your requirement following may be used:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
   $keyArray = explode(' ',$key);
   if(in_array('Packaged',$keyArray))
      echo "Key exists" ;
}
```

Comment: `for ($array as...`...?

Comment: Don't need to explode and create another array. Just use any string function on that key to find out if the key contains the term `Packaged`

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = "Package sdsd";

echo preg_match("/(Package)+/",$test);
```

you can use simple regex , as an example above if the Package word occurs the string the result will be true